# Flutter project files lost

Tags: git, flutter, dart

I have recently completed a flutter project and I decided to get it onto github to share it with other people. I created a repo, made a local git bash, added, committed and finally pushed all of my files to the repo. Suddenly I saw that a lot of files went missing and they did not even get added nor committed to my repo and now they are lost. These files include: all of my .dart files, all of my .yaml files and more. Can someone help me locate these files or help me not make a mistake like this again?

Edit:
Here is my .gitignore file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxv8i.png

And here is what my project structure looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HNKH.png

As you can see there is not even a pubspec.yaml file and my IDE does not see this project as a flutter project

I do have the completed app installed on my phone. Is there a way that I could get the code from my phone?

I also think that I still have the apk of the app if that can help.

Comment: Sounds like the files were excluded by way of `.gitignore`. But without more information it's not possible to say exactly what happened

Comment: @fredrik what more information can I provide to help?

Comment: I guess the simple solution for the next project is to make a backup first, before doing such manipulations.

Comment: But what we don't know is what operation you did that might have deleted the ignored files. Normally, ignored files are left in your working directory, they are not deleted. Did you run some aggressive cleanup command that implied deleting all ignored files, somehow?

Comment: As far as I know, you would have had to run something like `git clean`, possibly with `-x` or `-X`, to delete files that are not under source control, so did you do anything like that?

Comment: @joanis The only git commands that I ran were: git init, git add . , git commit -m "Initial commit", git remote add origin <my http>, git push origin master

Comment: Hum, I don't see anything wrong with what you did. No command you show here should have deleted any files. Maybe your IDE is configured to clean up ignored files, somehow, and you somehow triggered the IDE's clean-up operation? What's your IDE, anyway?

Comment: @joanis I checked my github commit history and those files did not even get committed to the repo. So the files went missing on the repo and also on my local machine.

Comment: @joanis I'm using android studio

Comment: The files might still be on your hard drive, Android Studio has some behaviour where it can seem that you have lost files or a project.  In my case, I had to close the project that was appearing instead of the project I was seeking, and then use Android Studio's 'open' button to search within the folder of projects - and there I found my Flutter project.  Before, I was noticing a kind of Android-only version of the project, so I was wondering what happened too.